# Visual Studio hang on "Performing registration"

Tags: visual-studio-2008, atl

I think this is pretty basic. Today I was building a dynamic link project which statically link to ATL. While building it, it hangs on the "Performing registration" stage and didn't proceed. I can see there is a regsvr32.exe in task manager. I guess this process it doing registration work. But it never ends.

So I canceled the build and try again, then I have some unresolved external symbol problem. Does anybody can explain to me why this is happening? thank you very much in advance!
Platform(Windows 7 64, VS 2008)

Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`regsvr32.exe` is loading your DLL, and calling its `DllRegisterServer` exported function. Supposedly it freezes, you can check it with task manager, Process Explorer, or debugger - attaching to frozen process. It is quite likely that the cause is thus within your DLL and you need to resolve it, attaching with debugger, or just starting debugging session with `C:\Windows\syswow64\regsvr32.exe <full path to your DLL>`.

Not that if your DLL is 32-bit, then you need `syswow64\regsvr32.exe`, and not `system32\regsvr32.exe` (or otherwise the debuggee will just start a child process which will freeze not being debugged).

Comment: The project don't have a DllRegisterServer. Only a module attribute like:[ module(dll, uuid = "{****-****-****-***-***}", 
   name = "module", 
   helpstring = "demo module",
   resource_name = "IDR_DemoModule") ];

Comment: It does have, it's in the base you are inheriting from. You can witness this using Dependency Walker app.

Answer (score 0):

check taskmanager, see what's the parameter passed into regsvr32.exe, normally register such dll get blocked by something, get what blocked, debug into the dllmain if possible.